# Find a stochastic process from known conditional expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

**General problem:**

Given a positive function $g(x,s)\geq 0$ with $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x,s)ds=\infty$ can we show the existence or lack thereof of some positive process $\{\lambda(t)\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ such that
$$
E\left[\lambda(t+s)|X(t)=x\right]=g(x,s)\\
\lambda(t) \geq 0\\
$$

<sup>(I.e the expected trajectory of some random hazard given data is given by some function of data)</sup>

**Particular problem:**

In particular, I'm trying to generate some interesting data from unknown $\lambda,X$ where I want $g$ to be given by
$$
g(x,s)=b(x)a(x) s^{b(x)-1}
$$
Or equivalently
$$
g(x,s)=\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)} \left(\frac{s}{\alpha(x)}\right)^{\beta(x)-1}
$$
Where $a,b$ or $\alpha,\beta$ are known strictly positive functions.

<sup>(I.e the expected trajectory of some random hazard given data is Weibull)</sup>

Does such a process exist? If so any (possibly trivial) suggestions? Any reading tips/hints on where this type of problem might have been studied?

Edit: Possibly helpful summary of properties of $g$. For all $s\geq0$ and real valued $x$:
$$
g(x,s)\geq 0 \\
\int_{0}^{s}g(x,\tau)d\tau=G(x,s)\\
G(x,\infty)=\infty\\
G(x,0)=0\\
$$ 
Also note that for each positive distribution parametrized by $x$ there's a $G$ s.t $Pr(T>t)=e^{-G(x,t)}$ and conversely $G(x,t)$ induces a probability distribution

Comment: I don't see where you've defined $X$...

Comment: I intentionally left this open for interpretation because I'm sure someone could look at this and see a particular family of SDEs or something. As far as I'm concerned it may be any process, even deterministic. I haven't had any luck when fixing $X$ yet so hoped to get a fresh eye on the problem. As an example, I've considered if $X(t)$ is 1d brownian motion and $\lambda(t)=f(X(t))$ then the problem is to find an $f$ s.t $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2s}}dy=g(x,s)$ but I haven't had any insights staring at this equation yet